# Eclipse silently refusing to add a reference to library project

Tags: android, eclipse

In my Eclipse workspace I have:

- A library project (MiSnap from Mitek). The project is marked "is library" in it's properties.
- existing Android app.

When I try to reference the library in the Android app (using properties window) the green checkmark appears. This seems to be working right But when I click apply/ok I don't see any auto-build happening. I open properties again for the app and the list of added libraries is now empty (I don't see green checkmark and I do not see any red X's). The list is empty.

I'm assuming I am doing something wrong. I've tried various things I found by searching stackoverflow. None of these things are working. Perhaps something unique is happening since my list is empty after I add a library instead of seeing a red X?

I'm not sure what other information you will need so I'll leave that part open to request.

Comment: Copy the library to your workspace and then try again. Also restarting eclipse help sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @rohan. The library is in my workspace and I have restarted Eclipse..many times.Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try: Delete the reference(just reference don't delete your code) of the library from eclipse. Then import again your library from your workspace; clean your projects, and on your app add again your library.

Comment: Is the autobuild activated?

Comment: I've tried with autobuild on and autobuild off and the import sequence as described by @Tobiel. With no luck.

Comment: Check the attributes od the files inside your project. Sometimes that happens when i switch from Mac and Windows. Maybe the file is invisible or read-only. Try to fix that or modify it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Open project.properties and add the below line

```
android.library.reference.1=..\\Library_Name
```